# Testing REST API

Tags: python, rest

I am developing a REST API on Django.  What do other uses to craft json msgs to test?  Is there a browser plugin, python lib, curl, something else?

Comment: You could also give [vREST](http://vrest.io) a try.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to write Python try using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) library to do some basic testing from the client side. There is a CLI tool based on this called [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) that you might also want to check out. You can also use curl for testing if you prefer the command line but it is probably easier to use Requests in the long run from Python code if you are dealing with a more complex API or want to do anything repeatedly.

Comment: Would you happen to know a way to generate a custom json POST from a browser?  Right now I am trying to test manually as I move along.

Comment: You can create an HTML form to post information. Alternatively tools like Fiddler on Windows let you handcraft requests and also view HTTP traffic as it happens.

Comment: If you are using Chrome you should definitely check out the REST Console extension. It will allow you to easily craft all sorts of requests and view the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The Python 2.6+ standard library includes the `json` module which should help you create some JSON objects to do testing.

Here is a link to the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

JSON is simple because you have a choice of JSON libraries to use in Python. Before you choose, read this article http://deron.meranda.us/python/comparing_json_modules/ because I suspect that you will find it very useful to use a strict parser for your testing. The benchmarks may be outdated, but the strict validating parsers are unlikely to have been superceded.

Write some Python code that acts as a web client, using a library like [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) to access your app. If your like a lot of people and all of your JSON is a single Javascript object, then you could keep your test data in any old database such as SQLite, read it into a Python dict, and encode it into a JSON object with one function call. Then for the actual test, after you receive a JSON reply, decode it into a dict and you have a normal Python object to use for comparisons.

Comment: Would you happen to know a way to generate a custom json POST from a browser?  Right now I am trying to test manually as I move along.

Comment: It is much, much easier to write a few lines of Python to post a JSON response rather than trying to muck around with something manually in a browser.